# Boton (x) en pestañas de un JTabbedPane

Tags: java, java-swing, botón

hola que tal estoy haciendo una app que lleva un JtabbedPanel es algo similar a lo que voy a postear

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen se ve el panel con pestañas (JtabbedPane) y ademas hay dos pestañas extras que son Pestaña 2 y pestaña 3 que son JnternalFrame.

la aplicacion consiste en que si presiono el boton crear pestaña 2 se crea la pestala y esta contiene al internalframe(Pestaña2), luego en pestaña2 hay un boton(Crear pestaña 3) al igual que el anterior al presionarlo se crea la pestaña3 junto con el internalframe(Pestaña3)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas imagenes es la aplicacion funcionando y creando las pestañas. Ahora bien lo que deseo es agregar e boton "**X**" a cada pestaña para de esta forma poder cerrarlas. se que se cierran por medio de **remove** pero no se como Añadir el boton...

aca dejo el codigo de como llamo a cada pestaña, use Netbeans para crear los paneles y los internalFrame

**Codigo del 1er boton (Crear pestaña 2)**

```
private void BtnPestaña1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    Pestaña2 segundaPestaña = new Pestaña2();
    Pestañas.add("Pestaña2", segundaPestaña);
    Pestañas.setSelectedComponent(segundaPestaña);}
```

**Codigo del 2do boton (Crear pestaña 3)**

```
private void BtnPestaña2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    Pestaña3 terceraPestaña = new Pestaña3();
    PanelPestañas.Pestañas.add("Pestaña 3", terceraPestaña);
    PanelPestañas.Pestañas.setSelectedComponent(terceraPestaña);
}
```

lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede hacer uso de un `JPanel` en donde se agrupen un `JLabel` para el texto del titulo del tab y un `JButton` para tener el control del clic, después de esto poner ese `JPanel` dentro de cada tab por medio del método `setTabComponentAt()`.

Suponiedo un `JTabbedPane` llamado `TP` instanciado y 'seteado' de la manera mas común, en el constructor de una clase que he llamado `Console`:

```
//...Constructor de clase
TP = new JTabbedPane();
TP.addTab("Pestana 1",null);
TP.addTab("Pestana 2",null);
TP.addTab("Pestana 3",null);
TP.addTab("Pestana 4",null);
for(int i=0;i<TP.getTabCount();i++) {
  TP.setTabComponentAt(i,new Cross(TP.getTitleAt(i))); //agrega titulo y boton X.
}
getContentPane().add(TP,BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
```

Luego el objeto `Cross` que es basicamente el `JPanel` que contendrá un `JLabel` y un `JButton` (con icono) para controlar los clics:

```
public class Cross extends JPanel {
  private JLabel L;
  private JButton B;
  private int size=10;

  public Cross(String title) {
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    gbc.weightx=1;
    L=new JLabel(title+" ");
    B=new JButton();
    B.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10,10));
    B.setIcon(getImage());
    //Listener para cierre de tabs con acceso estatico al `JTabbedPane`
    B.addActionListener(e->Console.TP.removeTabAt(Console.TP.indexOfTab(title)));
    add(L,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    gbc.weightx=0;
    add(B,gbc);
  }

  private ImageIcon getImage() {
    java.awt.Image IMG=null;
    try {
      IMG = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/cross.png")).getImage();
      IMG = IMG.getScaledInstance(size,size,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ImageIcon(IMG);
  }
}
```

Se logra algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho tu aclaracion gracias:D