# restaurar Tab JTabbed pabe

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Hace par de días realice el siguiente post:

[Añadir boton x al TAB](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255769/boton-x-en-pesta%C3%B1as-de-un-jtabbedpane/256257?noredirect=1#comment475362_256257)

Siguiendo con lo mismo ya logre añadirle el Boton x al tab.

Ahora bien, si cierro una de las pestañas ¿cómo hago para recuperarla?

No quiero que se me abran mas de 1 vez el mismo `tab` por ende declaro una variable.

```
public static Pestaña2 segundaPestaña
```

Ahora bien, al momento de llamar y crear el `tab` lo hago de la siguiente manera y me crea una sola `tab`.

```
private void BtnPestaña1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if(segundaPestaña == null){
        segundaPestaña = new Pestaña2(); 
        Pestañas.add("Pestaña2", segundaPestaña);
        Pestañas.setSelectedComponent(segundaPestaña);
        PanelPestañas.Botonx();
    }
}
```

Ese **Botonx** simplemente es el método que use para colocarle la **x** a las pestañas.

Ahora mi problema es para restaurar esa `tab` después de cerrarla como hago para desde el botón **Crear pestaña 2** poder restaurar ese `tab`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un método para ponerla y otro para quitarla:

```
public static Pestaña2 segundaPestaña;
public static boolean  estaPuestaLaSegunda = false;


static void muestraSegundaPestaña() {
   if (!estaPuestaLaSegunda) {
       if (segundaPestaña == null) {
           segundaPestaña = new Pestaña2(); 
       }
       Pestañas.add("Pestaña2", segundaPestaña);
       Pestañas.setSelectedComponent(segundaPestaña);
       estaPuestaLaSegunda = true;
   }
}
```

Y el método para quitarla:

```
 static void quitaSegundaPestaña {
     if (estaPuestaLaSegunda) {
        estaPuestaLaSegunda = false;
        Pestañas.remove(segundaPestaña);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, emplee solo la primera parte del codigo junto con el del post anterior y me funciona perfectamente